# Problemas com GLM

Tags: glm

Tenho a seguinte matriz:

```
      DIV   RIQ EXC FX_FREQ AMPL FQMIN FQMAX  FQDOM    DUR
BM 1.16  14   1       6         9950   250     10200   3254.4     173.77
CP 1.23  12   1       6         9840   260      10100   3417.5      84.06
MT 2.03  14   5       9         9955   160     10115   1359.8      60.70
```

A partir dela quero rodar um GLM.
O meu modelo global fica da seguinte forma (não estou utilizando nem RIQ, nem FX_FREQ):

```
M1<-glm(ADI ~ EXC+AMPL+FQMIN+FQMAX+FQDOM+DUR, family=poisson, data=env)
summary(M1)
```

Quando chamo o comando summary(M1), de cara obtenho:
Call:

```
glm(formula = ADI ~ EXC + AMPL + FQMIN + FQMAX + FQDOM + DUR, 
    family = poisson, data = env)

Deviance Residuals: 
[1]  0  0  0

Coefficients: (4 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  5.308e+00  1.162e+02   0.046    0.964
EXC          1.406e-01  2.996e-01   0.469    0.639
AMPL        -5.327e-04  1.177e-02  -0.045    0.964
FQMIN               NA         NA      NA       NA
FQMAX               NA         NA      NA       NA
FQDOM               NA         NA      NA       NA
DUR                 NA         NA      NA       NA

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance:  3.0247e-01  on 2  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: -3.2641e-16  on 0  degrees of freedom
AIC: Inf

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations:
```

O que me incomoda são esses "NA". Tento seguir a análise criando novos modelos, o critério que utilizo é: sempre no novo modelo, não insiro a variável com o maior valor de p obtido no modelo anterior. Ex: meu M2 é:

```
M2<-glm(ADI ~ EXC+FQMIN+FQMAX+FQDOM+DUR, family=poisson, data=env)
```

pois no summary(M1), a variável AMPL teve maior p. Prossigo até que me tenha 6 modelos.

No fim quero selecionar com base em Akaike (AiCc). Então aplico o comando:

```
AICc <- ICtab(M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,type = c("AICc"),base=T, weights = TRUE, 
        delta = TRUE, sort = TRUE, nobs = 4)
```

O maior problema ocorre quando chamo AICc. O que aparece é:

```
   AICc dAICc df weight
M1 Inf  NaN   3  NA    
M2 Inf  NaN   3  NA    
M3 Inf  NaN   3  NA    
M4 Inf  NaN   3  NA    
M5 Inf  NaN   3  NA    
M6 Inf  NaN   2  NA
```

Preciso resolver isso. Poderia me ajudar?